# Duplicate message requests in Skype4Java

Tags: java, skype4java

I have this code, and it works but sometimes it sends 2 messages to the person.

```
Skype.addChatMessageListener(new ChatMessageAdapter() {
    public void chatMessageReceived(ChatMessage received) throws SkypeException {
        if (received.getContent().equals("!server")) {
            // Sender
            received.getSender().send("Comando Em Manutenção");
        }
    })
```

How to solve this bug?

Comment: would it make sense to provide some context? What is ``received``?

Comment: Don't know much about skype4java, but found this bug report, which may be relevant to your case (doesn't appear to be fixed though): https://github.com/lemmy/skype4java/issues/3.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api . From the README: This project is a mavenization and release of Skype4Java with several bug fixes.

Comment: Wow this updated and not have double message bug more, this is helpful.

Comment: glad to hear it worked. I've posted this as an answer in case anyone's having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a [known issue in Skype4Java](https://github.com/lemmy/skype4java/issues/3).
Also, according to the [author's comment](https://github.com/lemmy/skype4java/issues/2#event-130564591), the project has been abandoned, but there is another one based on it: [Skype Java API](https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api).

From the README:

> This project is a mavenization and release of `Skype4Java` with
>   several bug fixes.